# Taylor series of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I wanted to find the Taylor series of the function $$\frac{\sin x }{x}$$ and found on wolfram alpha that it is equal to, in series representation, $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-1} \frac{x^n((-i)^n+i^n)}{2(1+n)!}.$$

Now this might be a stupid question but why is it not just the case of applying $\frac{1}{x}$ to the Taylor series of $\sin x$? Then finding it to be $$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{1}{x} \frac{(-1)^kx^{1+2k}}{(1+2k)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}  \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(1+2k)!}. $$

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: You've taken $\frac{1}{n}$ inside the infinite sum, but this is only valid if the resulting sum converges.

Comment: Do note that if you look at the "Series expansion" part of WA for $\sin x$ and then divide it by $x$ you get exactly the expansion for "Series expansion" of $\frac {\sin x} x$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two are in fact equal. Notice that $$\frac{(-i)^n+(i)^n}{2}$$ is $0$ when $n$ is odd and $\pm1$ when $n$ is even. So you can substitute $n=2k$.

Comment: Wow... right of course. My mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The CAS (computer algebra system) sometimes look to work thing out in a no optimal way, of course the results should be the same (yes, you can divide the sin(x) McLaurin series by x and get the power series for $sin(x)/x$, with $x\neq0$), so I wonder  that's what happens.